# Smart / Dump components: deep nesting with ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

Consider the following app layout:

[image]

Our app consists of a smart component **A** with a dumb component **A_dumb**. **A_dumb** contains dumb child components **B_dumb** and **C_dumb**, which are grandchildren of **A**.

**B_dumb** and **C_dumb** draw their data from **A**. Their view is, apart from their position within the view of **A_dumb** independent from **A_dumb**.

Most advice on distribution of data and handling of events goes either in the direction of bucket-brigading (A -> A_dumb -> B_dumb and vice versa) or using a unified service.

As I am using ngrx, I tend to not use the service as I do not want to deal with subscriptions and rather use the async pipe in the smart components template, which leaves me with bucket-brigading.

However, bucket-brigading is a lot of boilerplate and we have `<ng-content></ng-content>`. We could bind all dumb-components directly to our smart-component and then project them to the "main" dumb-component.

This is the smart component:

```
// a.html
<a-dumb [data]="mybinding$ | async">
  <b-dumb [data]="myotherbinding$ | async"></b-dumb>
  <c-dumb [data]="mythirdbinding$ | async"></c-dumb>
</a-dumb>
```

This is the view:

```
// a-dumb.html
<div class="...">
  ...
  <ng-content select="b-dumb"></ng-content>
  ...
  <ng-content select="c-dumb"></ng-content>
  ...
  <!-- having a sink is always nice :) -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

In my eyes this would make sense for widget-like grandchildren that do not directly belong to the view of the component but draw styling and positioning from the view.

I am interested in your opinions on that topic and pro and cons if this approach is desirable. Unfortunately, despite searching for this, I was unable to find any input...

Comment: You're looking for an opinion from SO and SO is not suitable place for this kind of question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: I am well aware of the "How do I ask a good question?" section. Although, I am not seeking answers for a problem of the proportions of "nothing works, help", I do seek the answer to a general design issue. If you actually read the [applicable help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you'll find that this question is perfectly fine by SOs own standards.

Comment: Are B_Dumb and C_Dumb static children of A_Dumb, meaning, does A_Dumb always instantiate the same components or are they dynamic/flexible?

Comment: In my case they are always the same until someone decides to swap them out. However, an interesting view would be if they are randomized or depending on data.

Comment: If they are the same, you might want to consider the following: 1) Make A_Dumb accept as input your data. 2) Assign the value in A [binding1]="binding1$ | async". 3) Have B_Dumb define and input for binding. 4) instantiate B_Dumb in a dumb with the input value <b-dumb [binding]="binding". (same applies for C_Dumb with its binding)